# How to sort variable data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating one function in javaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
     var str = "1,12,3,4";

     if (str.contains("1,12,4,3")) {
         alert("yes");
     } else {
         alert("No");
     }
}
```

o/p: NO..i want the o/p as "Yes " because all elements are there.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Great! Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: First of all str is a string not an array. and please mention exact question because elements are in array not in string.

Comment: Please read once, i updated the Question.
i want to check whether one variable data contains other or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compare the comma separated elements contained in the string, not the string itself.

So you can use `split` and `sort` to build and sort your arrays and an "equality function" to check them.

Ref:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You can try use a sorting/comaring function:

```
var str = "1,12,3,4";
var str2 = "1,12,4,3";

var myArray1 = str.split(",");
var myArray2 = str2.split(","); 

alert(arraysEqual(myArray1, myArray2))

function arraysEqual(a, b) {    

    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || b == null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    a.sort();
    b.sort();

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ZT4M8/

Answer (score 1):

String `"1,12,3,4"` really doesn't contain substring `"1,12,4,3"`. You're shuffling arrays and strings methods. You should convert your string to array (e.g. using `split()` method), then possible order and after all match.

Comment: i try to split but it's not splitting:

function myFunction() {
     var str = "1,12,3,4";

var b=str.split();
alert(b)

     if (str.contains("1,12,4,3")) {
         alert("yes");
     } else {
         alert("No");
     }
}
alert(b) also coming as comma seprated

Comment: Look Mr. Charma's answer below, his method should work like you need.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function myFunction() {
     var str = "1,12,3,4";
     var str_to_match = "1,12,4,3";
     var res = str.split(","); 
     var res_to_match = str_to_match.split(","); 
var flag=1;
     for(var i=0; i<res_to_match.length; i++)
     {
        if(!res.contains(res_to_match[i]))
        {
             flag=0;
             break;
        }
     } 
     if (flag==1) {
         alert("yes");
     } else {
         alert("No");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for are the functions split, join and sort:

```
var myArray = str.split(","); // creates an array with your numbers
myArray.sort(); // sorts the array
var sortedStr = myArray.join(","); // creates a comma separated string of the sorted array
```

Comment: this is not working, sorted array is not coming

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with "is not coming"?

Comment: i mean data is not in sorted order.

Comment: it will be sorted alphabetically so str="1,6,12,4,3" gets sortedStr="1,12,3,4,6" ...

Comment: so what's the point of sorting, i want the order in ascending order.

Comment: It IS an ascending order, but it sorts alphabetically, because you have a string. You can convert you strings into integers to have it sorted in numeric order.